# Difference between extract() and as.matrix() applied to a stan object

Tags: r, rstan

I have a Stan model (called `fit`) and I'm getting some strange results. I know that I'm probably missing something, but I can't see where and what. In this case I want to look at the parameter `sigma_h`.

If I use `as.matrix` to get the samples from `fit` I get the following result:

```
posterior <- as.matrix(fit) 
trace_sigma_h <- posterior[,colnames(posterior) %in% "sigma_h"]
ts.plot(trace_sigma_h)
```

[image]

This is the same plot I get when using the `rstan::traceplot`function.

If I extract the samples from the `fit`object and plots it I get

```
samples <- extract(fit,inc_warmup = FALSE)
ts.plot(samples$sigma_h)
```

[image]

These plots are not the same. What am I missing? Is there a difference between just making the `fit`object a matrix and extracting the samples?

Comment: It seems that `extract` uses `permuted = TRUE`, and so I guess it coulb be shuffling the order? Does it look like like the first with `permuted = FALSE`?

Comment: @Axeman and @J.C.Wahl: Yes entries from `extract` are shuffled by default (with a fixed seed). If you sort entries from both methods you can confirm that they are identical.

Comment: @Axeman and Maurits: Thanks for the response. You are both correct. Thank you very much. Is there a reason for shuffling the order?

Comment: Reason might be a strong word, but it was intended to prevent people from doing something like just analyzing some function of the first 100 draws.